# Product of Two Matrices is Zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B \in M_{m \times n}$, and $D \in M_{n \times n}$ such that $BD=0_{m \times n}$. If $D$ is a non-singular matrix, what can be said of $B$? Consequently, if we know what $B$ is, can we write $D$ in terms of $B$?

Comment: $BD=0$ with $\det D \neq0$ implies that $\det B=0$ since $\det B \cdot \det D =0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ has non-zero determinant, then it is actually invertible, and 
$$
B= BI = B(D D^{-1}) = (BD)D^{-1} = 0D^{-1} = 0
$$
Therefore, $B = 0_{m \times n}$. Nothing needs to be said about $D$.